# Cannot implement leaderboard on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

I'm trying to implement leaderboard for scores on my game. That package from git is imported on Unity 5.3 and when I copy-paste resources into the plugin setup dialog I got that errors message:

Plugin error: file not found: Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/template-Constants.txt

And this : Invalid classname: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can someone help me? :)

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, check that path to ensure that the file exists and check how you're referencing it in your code. Secondly, you should post the code that you're using to try to access the asset in your question, to help others assist you here.

Comment: I followed steps from: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/leaderboard-setup-for-android-in-unity

Comment: That file is in `Assets/Public/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor` in the repo.  Are you supposed to copy that somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

delete Assets/GooglePlayGames, and reinstall, Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Force Resolve, then you can go to setup android

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).